# Не могу понять в чем ошибка в коде

Tags: c++, функции, типы-данных, объявление

Не могу понять, в чем именно заключаются ошибки, поиск по названиям ничего дельного не дал, прикладываю код и скрин из CodeBlocks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

void  l( int & ans , vector < int >  d (), int x)
{
   if ( x == 10) return;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i)
    {
        if ( d[x-2] + d[x-1] + i == 11 )
        {
            ans = ans + 1;
            d[x] = i;
            l ( ans , d, x + 1);
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
   int ans;
   ans = 0;
   vector < int > d ( 10 , 0);
   for ( int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i)
   {
       ans = ans + 1;
       for  (int j = 1; j <= 7; ++i)
       {
           if ( i + j < 11)
           {
               ans = ans + 1;
               d[0] = i;
               d[1] = j;
               l ( asn , d, 2);
           }

       }

   }
   cout << ans;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `l ( asn , d, 2);` опечатка, `asn` вместо `ans`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector < int >  d ()
```

в

```
void  l( int & ans , vector < int >  d (), int x)
```

означает, что вы собираетесь вторым аргументом передать указатель на функцию, которая не принимает аргументов, и возвращает `vector<int>`. Это так? :)

А если нет - то описывайте тип аргументов правильно... Сами разберетесь, как? Намек: вы же не передаете третий, например, параметр как `int x()`...

Comment: Хм, мой косяк) Честно говоря считал , что с помощью скобок я как бы пересоздаю его в функции. Большое спасибо за оперативность! Там в любом случае остается ошибка в 39 строке 39|error: 'asn' was not declared in this scope|  и вот с ней тоже не знаю, что делать. Не подскажете?

Comment: @V-Mor Откатил ваше исправление. Я даже не был уверен, что стоит давать мой намек - потому что не стоит все разжевывать до такой мелочи, с дидактической точки зрения это неразумно. Когда человек доходит сам - он лучше запоминает...

Comment: А про `asn` вам уже подсказали - опечатка в имени. Простите уж, но **такое** понимать и замечать нужно самостоятельно...

Comment: @Harry Возможно, я хуже Вас разбираюсь в тонкостях принципов этого сайта, но я думал, что конкретный ответ будет полезнее. Возможно, впоследствии это прочитает кто-то, кто по незнанию не в состоянии будет понять даже такой намёк.

Comment: Тогда - в *строгом соответствии* с буквой сайта - вопрос вообще нужно закрытать, как вызванный очепяткой :)

Comment: @Harry, можете объяснить почему vector < int > d () = vector < int > (*d)()?

Comment: Имя функции автоматически рассматривается как указатель на нее и преобразуется в него. Так что, кстати, это тот случай, когда можно написать много звездочек :) - типа http://ideone.com/AM9DAk